# Chart/Graph/Monitoring data I get from an api in .json format

Tags: python-3.x, graph, automation, monitoring, grafana

I am looking for the best tool to automate the creating of graphs from QOS information I get from a videoconferencing service's API in .json format

I initially wanted to monitor this data but creating graphs would be good enough as I need to hit the API and compare QOS statistics for each meeting.

Is there a way to do this? I Like Python and thought about grafana but cannot find a way to do it.

This is an example of the data I get for each call. There are plenty of "user_qos" but it would be too long to paste here and I guess it can be understood as I pasted it.

I guess I should concentrate on the "user_qos" part and previously edit the file through Python.

```
{'next_page_token': '',
 'page_count': 1,
 'page_size': 10,
 'participants': [{'camera': 'Camera',
                   'connection_type': 'UDP',
                   'data_center': 'PP (Botom)',
                   'device': 'Rooms',
                   'domain': '',
                   'harddisk_id': '',
                   'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                   'ip_address': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                   'join_time': '2019-02-15T18:25:29Z',
                   'leave_time': '2019-02-15T19:20:19Z',
                   'location': 'Some Place (Earth)',
                   'mac_addr': '',
                   'microphone': 'USB audio CODEC',
                   'network_type': 'Wired',
                   'pc_name': '',
                   'recording': False,
                   'share_application': False,
                   'share_desktop': False,
                   'share_whiteboard': False,
                   'speaker': 'Built-in Output (Headphones)',
                   'user_id': '22222222',
                   'user_name': 'room',
                   'user_qos': [{'as_input': {'avg_loss': '0.0%',
                                          'bitrate': '39 kbps',
                                          'frame_rate': '8 fps',
                                          'jitter': '7 ms',
                                          'latency': '20 ms',
                                          'max_loss': '0.0%',
                                          'resolution': '1440*900'},
                             'as_output': {'avg_loss': '',
                                           'bitrate': '',
                                           'frame_rate': '',
                                           'jitter': '',
                                           'latency': '',
                                           'max_loss': '',
                                           'resolution': ''},
                             'audio_input': {'avg_loss': '',
                                             'bitrate': '',
                                             'jitter': '',
                                             'latency': '',
                                             'max_loss': ''},
                             'audio_output': {'avg_loss': '0.0%',
                                              'bitrate': '85 kbps',
                                              'jitter': '11 ms',
                                              'latency': '31 ms',
                                              'max_loss': '0.0%'},
                             'cpu_usage': {'system_max_cpu_usage': '69%',
                                           'avg_cpu_usage': '19%',
                                           'max_cpu_usage': '22%',
                                           'min_cpu_usage': '15%'},
                             'date_time': '2019-02-15T18:27:00Z',
                             'video_input': {'avg_loss': '0.1%',
                                             'bitrate': '0 kbps',
                                             'frame_rate': '',
                                             'jitter': '8 ms',
                                             'latency': '22 ms',
                                             'max_loss': '4.1%',
                                             'resolution': ''},
                             'video_output': {'avg_loss': '0.0%',
                                              'bitrate': '140 kbps',
                                              'frame_rate': '6 fps',
                                              'jitter': '11 ms',
                                              'latency': '28 ms',
                                              'max_loss': '0.0%',
                                              'resolution': '320*180'}},
                                {'as_input': {'avg_loss': '0.0%',
                                          'bitrate': '39 kbps',
                                          'frame_rate': '8 fps',
                                          'jitter': '7 ms',
                                          'latency': '20 ms',
                                          'max_loss': '0.0%',
                                          'resolution': '1440*900'},
                             'as_output': {'avg_loss': '',
                                           'bitrate': '',
                                           'frame_rate': '',
                                           'jitter': '',
                                           'latency': '',
                                           'max_loss': '',
                                           'resolution': ''},
                             'audio_input': {'avg_loss': '',
                                             'bitrate': '',
                                             'jitter': '',
                                             'latency': '',
                                             'max_loss': ''},
                             'audio_output': {'avg_loss': '0.0%',
                                              'bitrate': '85 kbps',
                                              'jitter': '11 ms',
                                              'latency': '31 ms',
                                              'max_loss': '0.0%'},
                             'cpu_usage': {'system_max_cpu_usage': '69%',
                                           'avg_cpu_usage': '19%',
                                           'max_cpu_usage': '22%',
                                           'min_cpu_usage': '15%'},
                             'date_time': '2019-02-15T18:27:00Z',
                             'video_input': {'avg_loss': '0.1%',
                                             'bitrate': '0 kbps',
                                             'frame_rate': '',
                                             'jitter': '8 ms',
                                             'latency': '22 ms',
                                             'max_loss': '4.1%',
                                             'resolution': ''},
                             'video_output': {'avg_loss': '0.0%',
                                              'bitrate': '140 kbps',
                                              'frame_rate': '6 fps',
                                              'jitter': '11 ms',
                                              'latency': '28 ms',
                                              'max_loss': '0.0%',
                                              'resolution': '320*180'}}],
                   'version': '4.1.33237.0924'}],
 'total_records': 2}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource . You can write python wrapper implementing SimpleJSON datasource api to return your data in grafana-ready format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuri, Will try it out